# How to obtain from a Map<Key,List<Value>> a List<Value>

Tags: java, dictionary

What is the best way to obtain from a Map a new List with all map values??

Is this correct?

```
List<Value> listValues = new ArrayList<>();
for(TypeKey keys : map.keySet()){
 for(TypeValue values : map.get(keys)){
  listValues.add(values);
 }
}
```

Comment: what is the type of `map`?

Comment: Why not use the [values()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()) directly instead of getting the keys first !?

Comment: in this case , the method values() return a Collection<List<Value>> but i want a List<Value>

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `Map<Key, Value>`, the `Map#values()` method will give you a `Collection<Value>`.

For a `Map<Key, List<Value>>`, the `values()` method will - obviously- give you a `Collection<List<Value>>` that can be flattend:

```
List<Value> values = map.values().stream()
                                 .flatMap(List::stream)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The method's name is `Map#values()`, with `s`, and it returns a `Collection`, not a `List`, but otherwise fine.

Comment: Another way since I can not use the stream in my case?

Comment: thanks for the hints @tobias_k.
@ LucaDeAngelis: see tobias_k's answer for 'manual' flattening.

Answer (score 1):

If you can not use the Java 8 `Stream` API, you can still make your code a bit shorter by using [`Map#values`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) to iterate the values lists directly, instead of the keys, and [`List#addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) to add all the values to the result list at once.

```
public <K, V> List<V> flatValues(Map<K, List<V>> map) {
    List<V> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<V> values : map.values()) {
        result.addAll(values);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public <K, V> List<V> flatValues(Map<K, List<V>> map) {
    List<V> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<V> values : map.values()) {
        result.addAll(values);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public <K, V> List<V> flatValues(Map<K, List<V>> map) {
    List<V> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<V> values : map.values()) {
        result.addAll(values);
    }
    return result;
}
```

i have used java stream